# Check in multiple columns and if find it return data from one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think the best way to describe my problem is with example, so I have this in my worksheet:

Let's say I have A-G columns, in column A I have data that I want to copy to column G if data entered in column F is anywhere found in columns from B to E, then column A needs to be copied to column G.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibc6l.png)

You can see what happens if enter data in F column, if finds if that data is anywhere in columns from B to E and if it finds it, it copy data from column A (in line where data was find) and copy it to column G.

All the data in columns from B to E are unique.

I've tried with vlookup and Index and Match combined but I've only mange to get that formula returns if finds data in first column (in my example column B) and if not, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in `G1`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT((B:E=F1)*ROW(B:E)))
```

However, it's always better to specify a range instead of full columns to safeguard performance.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now I have to look and study this formula a bit to understand it a bit better.